# Replacement Z Probe for MP10

Tags: z-probe, monoprice-mp-10

Has anyone successfully replaced the inductive Z probe on the Monoprice MP10 (Mini or regular) with a different type, such as BLTouch or IR?
I find that the stock inductive probe isn't so accurate, and since it's inductive it only works with the aluminum build plate but not with glass or PEI, which I much prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Thingiverse you can find a [BLTouch mount](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4375246) for the MP10 (and MP10 mini):

[image: MonoPrice MP10 BLTouch mount]

Note that in order to use the BLTouch sensor you need a different controller board that supports connecting a BLTouch sensor as the MonoPrice controller board doesn't support connecting a BLTouch sensor.

From [ref.](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4375246):

> A BLTouch adapter for the Monoprice MP10 & MP10 Mini. NOTE: you will need an open source control board to get this to work as the stock firmware on the MP10 line of products does not allow for a BLTouch.

Comment: What control board did you use?

Comment: @SZH I don't own a MP10, but there are plenty of boards out there nowadays, you are doing good by investing in a 32-bit controller board with enough drivers and options.